# "SCRIPT TO..." option in Datagrip?

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

Decided to pick up Datagrip for my Postgres database.

I've worked with SSMS/MS SQL-Server a lot, and one of the nice things about SSMS is the option to select a table and then a menu option called "SCRIPT TO..." and it'll give another list of auto-generated select, update, delete, etc queries.

Does Datagrip have a similar function? I'm struggling to find it.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/generation.html

Answer (score 0):

In DataGrip there is another concept of creating queries, editor-centered:

1. Live Templates. When you are in the editor you can quickly create any type of query. For example, for SELECT * FROM <table_name> just type `sel` and press Tab. Then choose the table. The same for INSERT (type `ins`). All live templates can be found in `Preferences | Editor | Live Templates`
2. `Generate` functionality: Alt+Ins or Cmd+N. It is not customizable but good to create objects.

Anyway, your point is fair and there is a feature request in DataGrips' tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2762. Please upvote and comment there.